# Как наглядно расположить граф в NetworkX?

Tags: python, графы, визуализация, чистый-код, networkx

Как сделать так, чтобы граф выглядел более наглядно?

Этот код выводит граф, но частенько вершины накладываются друг на друга:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Граф рисую по матрице смежности. Она представлена в конце сообщения.
Пробовал `draw_circular`, но это не совсем то, что нужно.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def Get_adjacency_matrix(filename): #cчитывание графа из файла
    adj_matrix = list()
    graphfile = open(filename, 'r')
    for l in graphfile:
        l = l.rstrip()[1:-1].split()
        for i in range(len(l)):
            l[i] = int(l[i])
        adj_matrix.append(l)
    graphfile.close()
    return adj_matrix

adj_matrix = Get_adjacency_matrix('MyGraph.txt')

G = nx.DiGraph(np.matrix(adj_matrix))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size = 300, arrows = True)
# cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'),
plt.show()
```

Матрица смежности (содержимое файла):

```
    [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выберете одно из [возможных расположений](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout) (`layout`) и укажите его явно:

```
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), with_labels=True, node_size=300, arrows=True)
# NOTE: -> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G), with_labels=True, node_size = 300, arrows = True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.planar_layout(G), with_labels=True, node_size = 300, arrows = True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и т.д. ...